# How to convert SQL into LINQ c# (Left Outer Join, Null assignment to string datatype and NVL() conversion mostly)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ. I would like to convert following SQL into C# LINQ.

Query:

```
SELECT s.Id, 
       s.Name, 
       s.Phone, 
       s.AssignedClasses, 
       d.name
FROM student s
INNER JOIN divison d ON s.Id = d.StudentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ld.Id, 
            ld.Name, //Datatype = String
            ld.Location, //Datatype = String
            ld.divisonId, 
            ld.lowerRange, 
            ld.upperRange
     FROM LocalDivison ld
     UNION All
     SELECT id.Id, 
            null, 
            null, 
            id.divisonId, 
            null, 
            null
      FROM InternationalDivision id) t
 ON t.divisonId = d.Id
 AND NVL(s.AssignedClasses,0) BETWEEN t.lowerRange AND t.upperRange
```

This what I have done so far:

```
    var innerQry = (from ld in localdivision
                   select new 
                   {
                     ld.Id, 
                     ld.Name, //Datatype = String
                     ld.Location, //Datatype = String
                     ld.divisonId, 
                     ld.lowerRange, 
                     ld.upperRange
                   }).Union
                   (from id in InternationDivison
                    select new
                    {
                      id.Id, 
                      null, //This throws compile time error. Can't assign string datatype field to null. How to do it?
                      null, //This throws compile time error. 
                      id.divisonId, 
                      null, 
                      null
                    })   

    var students =   from s in student
                     join d in divison on s.Id equals d.StudentId
                     join i in innerQry on i.divisionId = d.Id into temp
                     from final in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where (s.AssignedClasses ?? 0) >= innerQry.lowerRange && (s.AssignedClasses ?? 0) <= innerQry.upperRange  //I am not sure if I am doing this right.
                     select new
                     {
                       s.Id, 
                       s.Name, 
                       s.Phone, 
                       s.AssignedClasses, 
                       d.name
                     }
```

I was not able to convert union with null assignment for string datatype, left outer join and NVL() function.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: So, how far have you got? show us your progress, this isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG, I have updated my original post.

Comment: LINQ is *NOT* a replacement for SQL. Either create proper entities with relations and let your ORM generate the query or create a *view* and map your entities to it. The `Student` class should have a `Division` property and `Division` a `Students` collection.

Comment: BTW even as SQL, this is a bad query. What's the point of including `InternationalDivision` when it will *never* produce results? Its (implied) lowerRange and upperRange fields will always fail the comparison because they are NULL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - this is just an example.

Comment: @user659469 that's a good example of a *smell*. LINQ isn't SQL and the only reason we use ORMs is so we *don't* have to write all the SQL code ourselves. In this case the solution is to either fix the original context or create a new one. Nothing says you have to use *one* context for an entire application